# The State of a listView item in the DrawItem event is wrong

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

The question is in the code. Cannot understand why this is happening.

```
private void listView_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e)
{
    // This works Ok
    if (e.Item.Selected)
    {
        // ...
    }

    // This works wrong!
    // e.State is always Selected! Why?
    if ((e.State & ListViewItemStates.Selected) != 0))
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Does someone have a similar problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This looks like a known bug since about 2006, in evidence when the `ListView.HideSelection` property is set to `FALSE`.

The only workaround on file is to do what you've already done: use `e.Item.Selected`.

[Here](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/146557/drawlistviewitemeventargs-reports-incorrect-selection-information-when-set-listview-hideselection-property-to-false) is a link to the bug report - looks like it's been relegated to low priority so far.

Comment: Thank you. Actually after some debugging and playing with the ListView properties I found this by myself. Just wasn't sure is it a bug or a feature. Now it's clear.